# how do i sign an apk that has already been created without admin?

Tags: apk, command-prompt, digital-signature

no admin
created a Godot apk that I can't sign.
I need to sign an already existent apk.
need a command line command to do this properly which I cannot find.

YouTube (failed to do it)

Comment: Sorry but your title does not make sense at all. If you need to sign an APK use `apksigner` from Android SDK. Or there are other tools for PC and even apps that can sign an APK.